# How to filter a nested relation in Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Let's take this example: I have a form, which has several sections, each having questions. Sideways, I have answers that are mapped to questions and they have another column that I want to filter on when querying:

[image: Database schema]

So I have the following entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "sections")
public class Section {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String title;
}
@Entity(tableName = "questions")
public class Question {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String title;
    public long sectionId;
}
@Entity(tableName = "answers")
public class Answer {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public long questionId;
    public int otherColumn;
}
```

In the section DAO I want to retrieve all of them.

Here's the POJO that I want filled by this query:

```
class SectionWithQuestions {
    @Embedded
    public Section section;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "sectionId", entity = Question.class)
    public List<QuestionWithAnswer> questions;

    public static class QuestionWithAnswer {
        @Embedded
        public Question question;

        @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "questionId", entity = Answer.class)
        List<Answer> answers;
    }
}
```

In another application, the query would be:

```
SELECT s.*, q.*, a.*
FROM sections s
LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.sectionId = s.id
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.questionId = q.id
WHERE s.id = :sectionId and a.otherColumn = :otherColumn
```

However in Room I have found out that if you want an object and their relations (like a user and its pets in the example), you only select the object, and the relations are queried in a second query. That would be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE id = :sectionId")
```

Then in the generated code there would be (pseudo code):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE id = :sectionId" // what's inside @Query
cursor = query(sql)
int indexColumn1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(col1)
int indexColumn2
... etc
while (cursor.moveToNext) {
    masterObject = new object()
    masterObject.property1 = cursor.get(indexColumn1)
    ... etc

    __fetchRelationshipXXXAsYYY(masterObject.relations) // fetch the child objects
}
```

and this `__fetch XXX as YYY` method is as follows:

```
sql = "SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM a WHERE foreignId IN (...)"
similar algo as previously: fetch column indices, and loop through the cursor
```

So basically it creates 2 queries: one for the master object and one for the relations. The 2nd query is automatically created and we have no control over it.

To get back to my problem where I want relations but also filter on the child column, I'm stuck:

- in the 1st query I can't reference the `otherColumn` column because it doesn't exist
- in the `@Relation` I can't either because the only properties of this annotation are the join column and entity definition

Is this possible in Room or do I have to make the subqueries myself?

Bonus question: why don't they join tables in a single query but create 2 queries instead? Is this for performance reasons?

---

Edit to clarify what I expected:

That's what I expected to write:

```
@Query("SELECT s.*, q.*, a.* " +
       "FROM sections s " +
       "LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.sectionId = s.id " +
       "LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.questionId = q.id " +
       "WHERE s.id = :sectionId and a.otherColumn = :additionalIntegerFilter")
SectionWithQuestionsAndAnswers fetchFullSectionData(long sectionId);

static class SectionWithQuestionsAndAnswers {
    @Embedded Section section;
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "sectionId", entity = Question.class)
    List<QuestionWithAnswers> questions;
}
static class QuestionWithAnswers {
    @Embedded Question question;
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "questionId", entity = Answer.class)
    Answer answer; // I already know that @Relation expects List<> or Set<> which is
                   // not useful if I know I have zero or one relation (ensured
                   // through unique keys)
}
```

That's pseudo code that I imagined to be implemented by Room as the generated code:

```
function fetchFullSectionData(long sectionId, long additionalIntegerFilter) {
    query = prepare(sql); // from @Query
    query.bindLong("sectionId", sectionId);
    query.bindLong("additionalIntegerFilter", additionalIntegerFilter);
    cursor = query.execute();
    Section section = null;
    long prevQuestionId = 0;
    Question question = null;
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        if (section == null) {
            section = new Section();
            section.questions = new ArrayList<>();
            section.field1 = cursor.get(col1); // etc for all fields
        }
        if (prevQuestionId != cursor.get(questionIdColId)) {
            if (question != null) {
                section.questions.add(question);
            }
            question = new Question();
            question.fiedl1 = cursor.get(col1); // etc for all fields
            prevQuestionId = question.id;
        }
        if (cursor.get(answerIdColId) != null) { // has answer
            Answer answer = new Answer();
            answer.field1 = cursor.get(col1); // etc for all fields
            question.answer = answer;
        }
    }
    if (section !=null && question != null) {
        section.questions.add(question);
    }
    return section;
}
```

That's one query, and all my objects fetched.

Comment: "In the section DAO I want to retrieve all of them" -- not according to the rest of your question. You only want to retrieve the subset of those that have an associated `Answer` with a particular value for `otherColumn`. "Is this possible in Room" -- not in a single request AFAIK. You would need to make appropriate requests of appropriate DAOs and stitch the results together. "why don't they join tables in a single query but create 2 queries instead? Is this for performance reasons?" -- my guess that's its for "geez, this is only 1.0.0, gimme a break" reasons. :-)

Comment: What I mean is in another application (plain Java, PHP, anything), I would use the request with the two joins, which would return one section, all of its questions, and the answers if any. So I would get one section, many questions, each having possibly one answer. That's one query, and many objects from that single query. It seems that Room is unable to process that one query for all my objects. It appears that I have to use one query to select one section and all its questions, and then loop the questions and query the answers. That's 2 steps in the DAO, and 2 queries + 1 query per question.

Comment: "It seems that Room is unable to process that one query for all my objects" -- I haven't looked at the generated code for a three-level hierarchy such as yours, but what you describe would not surprise me. You can file [a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448); my guess is that it will be a post-1.0.0 initiative.

Comment: Actually the 2nd level of relation is not my issue here, I have badly designed my question. What's relevant is the filter on the joined table, which can't be set because the joined table is not actually a JOIN, and I can't add filters to the relation other than the relation IDs. I'd like to filter `answer.otherColumn`. Maybe that's a feature request then. I have edited my question with more details about what I was expecting.

Comment: To get more perspective, on one side I have _forms_ (1 form has several sections, and several questions per section), on the other I have _replies_ (one reply that matches one form, and many answers). So each answer object has one FK to the question object it is answering to, and another FK to the reply object it belongs to. I could add these tables to the schema picture of my question if that's not clear.

Comment: Re: feature request: [posted #65509934](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65509934)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just pasting the information provided on the feature request I posted (see my comment on my question):

> Hi there - we have recently released a new feature where relational query methods can be defined with Multimap return types. With this new feature, you should be able to achieve the results discussed in this thread. For more info on this new feature, you can check out the following resources:
>
> - Define relationships between objects: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships
> - Relational Query Methods in ADS 2021: https://youtu.be/i5coKoVy1g4?t=344
> - The new MapInfo annotation: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/MapInfo

I know link-only answers aren't great, but I didn't have the opportunity to test this. If someone has a better answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I find Room Relations hard to work with, not very flexible and much of the work is done under the hood in a way that is hard to really be sure how.

In my projects, most of the time I just create presentation objects - objects dedicated for some UI presentation that can be filled with a custom select.

That way I have much more control over what I want to fetch from DB (i.e. what I really need), and I fill that into that custom presentation object.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution for this. Instead of aliasing all columns you can use `@RawQuery` annotation.

First of all, add a prefix for embedded table annotation using table name or its alias like `@Embedded(prefix = "P.")` or `@Embedded(prefix = "Post.")`:

```
public class UserPost {

    @Embedded
    private User user;

    @Embedded(prefix = "P.")
    private Post post;

}
```

Then in your Dao, create a function to run a raw query, and create another function to run a raw query:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    String USER_POST_QUERY = "SELECT U.*, P.* FROM User as U " +
            "INNER JOIN Post as P ON U.id = P.userId " +
            "WHERE P.status = 1";

    @RawQuery
    LiveData<List<UserPost>> rawQuery(SimpleSQLiteQuery query);

    default LiveData<List<UserPost>> getAlertViolationsAsync() {
        return rawQuery(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(USER_POST_QUERY));
    }
}
```